# Unit Testing a Django Form Containing Multiple Submit Buttons

Tags: django, unit-testing, forms

I am writing unit tests for a page that uses several Submit buttons to control logical flow through my Django application.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the response to return the submit values in the unit testing framework.  The Django unit testing documentation for post indicates its form is the following:

```
post(path, data={}, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT, follow=False, **extra)
```

In the case of a Delete button of the form:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
```

I've tried placing the Delete value in as data, i.e.:

```
response = self.client.post(url, {'name':'delete'}, follow=True)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  I need to have the name values in order to exercise the code paths that they trigger.  In the views, the logic takes the form of:

```
if 'delete' in request.POST:
    <do something>
```

I'm assuming that I make use of **extra somehow to get these values but I haven't had much luck with it either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data dictionary should map input names to values. In your case, the name is `delete`, and the value is `Delete`. So the dictionary should be:

```
{'delete': 'Delete'}
```